# Google Sheets query doesn't display all values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a `Google Sheet` with the following query formula:

```
=QUERY('Contact Changes'!B1:T,"SELECT C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,R,S WHERE T='RMT'")
```

The source sheet displays the following results when filtering column `T` by `RMT`. So, the `Query` formula should produce the same results.

[image]

However, column `L` does not display the field values when they are text values:
[image]

If you look in `J126` (city column), you can see the value of `asdf` which **is** displayed correctly in the results `H2`. But, the same value in `L126` is not displayed in the results `L2`. The only way I can get a value to display in this column is by entering numbers.

I have:

- checked the column data format
- tried removing and re-adding the column in the `Query`
- changing the column order
- entering the same values in a different column (they display in the results)
- manually re-entering the values in the same column (they don't display in the results)

Am I missing something obvious? What else can I try?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google sheets `query` accepts only one data type per column, it detects automatically:

- if Col contains more taxt values: returns text
- if Col contains more numbers: returns numbers.

I solved the same problem with two workarounds:

- use `filter` or combine `filter` with `query`
- make extra column and convert all values into text by adiing any char, and then get rid of it.

---

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

> In case of mixed data types in a single column, the majority data type
>   determines the data type of the column for query purposes. Minority
>   data types are considered null values.

Comment: It is helpful to know that Query auto-sets the data type and accepts only one. However, it seems that the filter, or adding and removing a column is lots of extra work. Why not just set the source column values to `plain text`?

Comment: You may try asking this Q on Google forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/JoNRvkhVomI;context-place=forum/docs

Comment: I'm trying to combine `filter` with `query`... Can you please show an example? Should I use ArrayFormula? P.S. I am doing that in other GSheet through `importRange`. Looks like there is no a workaround :(

Comment: I have a similar problem but it doesn't seem to be solved in the same way. When the result of the query is less than three lines, only columns with numbers are shown, not those with text. Anyone know why this may be due?

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Max' contribution, you can also preprocess the data so that it's all converted to text and THEN wrap the query around this output. Something like

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(TO_TEXT('Contact Changes'!B1:T)),"SELECT Col3, Col4,    Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14, Col17, Col18 WHERE Col19='RMT'")
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in the past and today I tried to just format the entire column to "plain text" and it worked perfectly.

No problems anymore and every value is displayed.

Comment: Just be advised that one has to go update that formatting regularly, as it usually is lost for new entries into the database.

Answer (score 1):

An example of combining with Filter with Query for those who may find it helpful:

```
=QUERY(FILTER('Original Statement'!A:Z, 'Original Statement'!A:A = "Trades"), "select *")
```